# what is the intuition for the variance of poisson distribution being lambda

Tags: intuition, poisson-distribution, variance

poisson distribution: $P(X=x)=\frac{\lambda^x e^{−x}}{x!}$,

It is easy to understand the mean the distribution equal to $\lambda$, but what is the intuition for the variance being equal to $\lambda$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variance of the sum of independent random variables is the sum of their variances. The Poisson distribution is the limit of a binomial distribution in which the number of trials goes to infinity while the expected total number of successes is held constant at $\lambda$. Divide a (say, unit) time interval into $n$ subintervals and consider each interval to contain a success with probability $\frac\lambda n$. The corresponding binomial distribution is the sum of $n$ Bernoulli distributions, each with expectation $\frac\lambda n$ and variance $\frac\lambda n\left(1-\frac\lambda n\right)$, so the expectation of the sum is $\lambda$ and the variance of the sum is $\lambda\left(1-\frac\lambda n\right)$. As $n\to\infty$, the variance goes to $\lambda$.

Comment: for a Bernoulli distribution, p(1) = p, p(0) = 1-p, the variance is p*(p-1)^2 + (1-p)*p^2 = p(1-p). is there an intuition way to think about p(1-p) as variance?

Comment: @user7586189: If $p=0$ or $p=1$, all the results are the same, so the variance is zero. If $p=\frac12$, all the results are $\frac12$ away from the mean, so the standard deviation is $\frac12$, so the variance is $\frac14$. And $p(1-p)$ is the lowest-degree polynomial in $p$ that interpolates between those three points. Is that intuitive enough? :-)

Comment: yes, yes! thanks a lot:-)