# Alternate proof for variance of a Poisson random variable?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, poisson-distribution, variance, poisson-process

We know that Poisson random variable is the limiting case of a binomial random variable with parameters n and p, where n $\rightarrow \infty,  p \rightarrow 0$ and $np = \lambda < \infty$ ($\lambda$ is finite).

Variance of a binomial random variable is equal to $np(1 - p)$.

So, variance of Poisson random variable

= $\lim_{p \to 0} np( 1 - p)$

= $\lim_{p \to 0} \lambda (1 - p)$

= $\lambda$

Is this kind of proof considered to be correct?
If not, what is wrong with this reasoning?

Comment: There are three questions that need to be answered. (1) What does it mean to take a limit "as $n\to\infty$ and $np=\lambda$"? (2) In what precise sense does that sequence of binomials converge to a Poisson? and (3) For that form of convergence, is the variance of the limit equal to the limit of the variances?

Comment: This question is related to (and perhaps based on?) [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2906247) (which answered a question about intuition and doesn't purport to be rigorous).

Comment: The title contains a different question than the text. Please resolve the discrepancy.

Comment: @JackM (1) It means p and n are related in such a way that as one approaches infinity, the other approaches to zero but their product approaches a finite limit. For example, consider $n = \frac{\alpha}{p}$.

Comment: @JackM I don't know what you mean by the third point.

Comment: Actually, it seems you are suggesting a proof that nowhere uses the convergence (in distribution) of binomial $(n,p_n)$ to Poisson $\lambda$ when $np_n\to\lambda$ and $n\to\infty$. You are only using the known values of the variance of binomial $(n,p_n)$ and Poisson $\lambda$ and the trivial analysis result that, under these conditions, $np_n(1-p_n)\to\lambda$.

Answer (score 1):

This is not at all a proof, not to say a correct proof. Just because something holds for every element in a convergent sequence does not mean it also holds at the limit. For example, each element in $\frac11,\frac12,\frac13,\cdots$ is nonzero, but the limit is zero. That is what JackM means by his third point, because you cannot anyhow claim that the variance of the limit is equal to the limit of the variance. And worse still, you did not even specify what you mean by "Poisson random variable is the limiting case of a binomial random variable ...". Vague words do not constitute a proof.

Comment: Fully agree, naturally (+1). An additional point, though: extra uniform integrability conditions do allow to deduce convergence of variance from convergence in distribution.